# Command to `phpdoc` an entire directory?

Tags: php, phpdoc

What would the command line be to generate phpdoc for an entire project?

### Directory Structure

```
/Users/macuser/Sites/my-project/
    index.php
    config.php
    includes/
        class/
            test.class.php
        include-a.php
    docs-go-in-here/
```

I have installed PEAR phpdoc and am able to create documentation for a single php file, I cannot find out how to do an entire directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

phpdoc -h is your friend:

```
  -d    --directory               name of a directory(s) to parse
                                  directory1,directory2
```

Comment: thanks `-h` is really useful to know. `-d` seems to have done the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest considering using doxygen instead of phpdoc, which is a dead project. Check this out - http://www.doxygen.nl/

Comment: What are the notable pros / cons with doxygen when compared to phpdoc? Please bare in mind that my source is already heavily commented with phpdoc blocks.

Comment: The article at http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/9/4-reasons-consider-doxygen-over-phpdocumentor explains the differences quite well.

Comment: Doxygen understands the PHPDoc block syntax, so I didn't have problems switching to it from PHPDoc. What I also found very useful is the search functionality and UML class inheritance diagrams being part of the generated documentation. It's also worth mentioning that it allows you to have a separate page with everything marked with @todo in your code (so you get a nice list of things to be done/refactored etc.).

Comment: This might be a nice example: http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classBasicTimeZone.html

Comment: thank you for your comments, they are much appreciated. I like the example output that you referenced, quite a smart!